# How to dynamically call a function from a directory with python files

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on my first coding project, a recipe scraping tool.
Basically, you enter a recipe URL, it detects the recipe's website and it scrapes the requested recipe data.

Because I plan to write scrapers for at least 50+ websites, i have saved them as separate .py files (e.g. bonappetit.py, bbc.py) and saved them in a dedicated folder called /scrapers/. Each .py file holds a function called scrape(), which I can access from my main python file as follows:

```
# Scrape a Bon Appetit recipe:
recipe_data = bonappetit.scrape(url)

# Scrape a BBC recipe:
recipe_data = bbc.scrape(url)
```

How can I do this dynamically? I would like to code it something like this (this is fictonal code)

```
# Detect which scraper to use:
scraper = check_recipe(url)

# Dynamically call appropriate scraper function:
recipe_data = {scraper}.scrape(url)
```

Obviously, when i just hackishly write

```
recipe_data = scraper.scrape(url)
```

It returns an error, saying the str 'scraper' does not have an attribute called 'scrape'.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You could put them into a dictionary. If you're importing them like this `import bonappetit` `import bbc` you could map your imports to a dict of the sites main url like so. `urls = {r'https://www.bbc.co.uk' : bbc,  r'https://www.bonappetit.com' : bonappetit}` then if you have some way to parse the home url out you could call the scrapers like so. `urls[home_url].scrape(url)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Axe319. Actually, I already tried this since I store the appropriate scraper name in the Flask session, which is a dictionary. It still gives the following error: 
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'scrape', since it is just grabbing a string from the dictionary, e.g. 'bonappetit'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this through the getattr() method. The problem was that I tried to use the .scrape attribute on a str, which is not callable.

To use the dynamically generated str to dynamically create a callable object, i used the following code:

```
domain = check_recipe(url)
scraper = getattr(scrapers, domain)
recipe_data = scraper.scrape(url)
```

Where 'scrapers' refers to the folder with .py files that contain the actual scrape functions.

Please note that, for this to work, you will have to use a proper **init.py** file in the scrapers folder, in which you import all .py scrapers.